# Why we can't add an iterator with integer?

Tags: c++, stl

I want to print all the values of a set by iterator. After printing all values I want to print a `endl` without the last one.Here is my code:

```
for (set<string> :: iterator it = str_set.begin();it!=str_set.end(); it++)
{
     cout<<*it;
     if((it+1)!=str_set.end())  //here I got error ...
     cout<<endl;
}
```

But I got an Error while  checking `if((it+1)!=str_set.end())` .What is the wrong here?

Here is the error message:

```
error: no match for ‘operator+’ (operand types are ‘std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator’ {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >’} and ‘int’)
   92 |         if(it+1!=str_set.end())
      |            ~~^~
      |            |  |
      |            |  int
      |            std::set<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::iterator {aka std::_Rb_tree_const_iterator<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >}
```

Comment: `set<string> it`? Don't you mean `set<string>::iterator it`? Or better yet `auto it = str_set.begin()`.

Comment: Only the iterators where `it+n` can be computed in constant time for any n were given an operator+. For others, you have `std::next`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> What is the wrong here?

[`std::set::iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) is a [Constant *LegacyBidirectionalIterator*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator). There is no binary `+` operator between such an object and an `int`.

You can use [`std::next`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next) to get the next iterator. That would be idiomatic.

```
 if ( std::next(it) != str_set.end() )
    cout << endl;
```

Answer (score 2):

[`std::set::iterator`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator) has no `operator+()`. You can only increment it and decrement (1) it:

```
it++; // increments
it--; // decrements
```

If you want only check the next one, you can use a temporary iterator:

```
auto tmp = it; // assuming you can use "auto" here
tmp++;

if((tmp++)!=str_set.end())
```

Of course, in the code you have given us, it's probably better to just increment it directly

```
if((it++)!=str_set.end())
```

But it really depends on what you're trying to do here.

---

(1) Minor [warning about decrementing `begin()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/BidirectionalIterator):

> **Notes**
>
> The begin iterator is not decrementable and the behavior is undefined if --container.begin() is evaluated.
>
> A bidirectional iterator does not have to be dereferenceable to be decrementable (in particular, the end iterator is not dereferenceable but is decrementable)

So don't decrement `begin()`.

Answer (score 1):

`set`s iterators are Bidirectional. This means that you can increment and decrement them, but not do generalized addition on them. For that you need "Random Access" iterators.

You can make your code work by defining `set<string>::iterator last = --str_set.end();` and then comparing against that. (Note that this will do bad things if the set is empty).